# Trouble with a line of SQL in my java program

Tags: java, sql

So the program is the connecting to a .mdb file as our data base. I have written all the other code to the program and know it works fine but I am now having trouble with a complex SQL statement being passed as a parameter to a createQuery(Sring, int) method.

There are two tables
Person, which has Name, Id, City, State
Classes, which has Id, Course, Grade

The intended purpose of this line is to print out "Name and Id" from a table of Persons and also print "Course and Grade" from the Classes table. The query only prints entries with matching Id's(Person.Id = Classes.Id), in a specific Course('CSC 225'), and that have a Grade > 70.

We never were taught the SQL statements in any depth so my basic understanding has concocted the following lines of code.

```
String s = "SELECT " + personTableTitle + ".Name, " + personTableTitle + ".Id, " + 
                            classesTableTitle + ".Course, " + classesTableTitle + ".Grade FROM " +
                            personTableTitle + " " + classesTableTitle + " WHERE " +
                            personTableTitle + ".ID = " + classesTableTitle + ".Id AND " +
                            "Course = 'CIS 225' AND " + classesTableTitle + ".Grade > 70 AND " +
                            personTableTitle + ".Id = ? AND " + classesTableTitle + ".Id = ?";

System.out.print(s);   // Double check of my SQL Statement before passing

db.createQuery(s, 4);
```

I have been playing with this SQL statement since Wednesday night and haven't been having much luck.

Comment: what exactly do you want to get from your query? the persons or the classes or if both how are they supposed to be connected to retrieve them both? right now you have two tables, ok, but what do they have to do with each other?

Comment: What is the error?  I can't help but notice that the spelling (capitalization) of your ID field is **not** consistent.  You have it in all caps one time.  That said, we have no idea what error you're getting (because you haven't told us).  Please edit the question with more info...

Comment: Your `FROM` looks like `FROM personTable classesTable WHERE` but should be `FROM personTable, classesTable WHERE`. You are missing a comma between the table names.

Comment: A good way to catch an error like this is to try running the query outside of your program.  I notice you're already printing out the query. Take that output and paste it into whatever tool you use to interact with your database.

Comment: Why don't you just write the SQL query statement without the variables? Do you expect the table names to change or to be configured somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I only see two problems.  Sql needs commas between the table names in the `FROM` clause, i.e. `...FROM table1, table2 WHERE...`.  So change your line to

```
             personTableTitle + ", " + classesTableTitle + " WHERE " +
```

This next one might not be a problem, but it's a good idea to include the table name in front of every field reference.

```
             classesTableTitle + ".Course = 'CIS 225' AND " + classesTableTitle + ".Grade > 70 AND " +
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me figure out what I was doing wrong in the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try your query directly on the database (console or GUI). Once your query is valid, you'll be able to translate it very quickly back into Java.

Otherwise, it's good practice to add an alias to tables; for example:

```
select *
from Person P, Classes C
where P.Name = 'joe' and P.id = C.id
```

You may also need to do an `outer join` to get your data (look at how to do joins for your database).

Comment: I will have to start doing that more in the future. Definitely would make the code a lot smoother to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would suggest for SQL code

```
String s = "SELECT P.Name, P.Id, ";
s = s + "C.Course, C.Grade ";
s = s + "FROM Person P ";
s = s + "JOIN Classes C  ";
s = s + "ON P.ID = C.ID ";
s = s + "WHERE Course = 'CIS 225' AND C.Grade > 70;";
```

I split up each assignment into its own line.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it everyone, thanks for the help.

I started rewriting it using the suggestions posted and came up with this as the string:

```
String s = "SELECT Person2.Name, Person2.Id, Classes.Course, Classes.Grade FROM Person2, Classes WHERE Classes.Id = Person2.Id AND Classes.Course = 'CIS 225' AND Classes.Grade >70";
```

It works so I can make it more presentable now. The reason I am using my variable names from java in the original post was that is what the teacher wanted. She is very stubborn and has taken off points from my material for things as simple as writing`s += whatever;` instead of `s = s + whatever;`